# Ubuntu not booting when switching from Wayland to Xorg

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, wayland, intel-graphics

It's Ubuntu 22.04 on dual boot with Windows 10. I'm using Intel HD 620 Graphics. Not sure if it's causing the issue.

It works great on Wayland but when I switch to Xorg by editing /etc/gdm3/custom.conf file and setting: WaylandEnable=false

It's ok, until I reboot or restart the gdm3 service. Then it never boots to the OS. The only way out is go to recovery mode, and switch back to Wayland.

I've tried enabling networking and repairing packages. Saw a solution for Radeon card somewhere so thought it might be a driver issue.

I love using Wayland but recently Upwork has disabled support for screen captures via their desktop app until you switch to Xorg. It's really frustrating and I can't seem to find an alternate on their community page too.

Comment: You can and should select "Xorg" in the login screen, NOT edit anything else.

Comment: It does boot. It's just that the change you made in some way disabled the display.

Answer (score 0):

I did not have Display Manager Options at the login screen, whenever I researched, all I could find was to edit the custom.conf file.
But I installed Xorg from apt, and I had the options to switch between sway/Xorg/default at the login screens now.